# Why are my Cura generated thumbnails showing in one flat color without any depth?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, g-code, octoprint

I recently started using this [Slicer Thumbnails](https://plugins.octoprint.org/plugins/prusaslicerthumbnails/) plugin in OctoPrint and added the steps to my Cura 5.5 slicer. However, my thumbnails are in one color, like this:

[image: Screenshot of the Slicer Thumbnails plugin for Cura slicer showing the model as a single, all-black image]

And are not showing any depth as shown for example on the plugin page:

[image: Screenshot of the Slicer Thumbnails webpage showing a multi-colored preview thumbnail]

Am I missing something here or is there a better way to create and add beautiful thumbnails?

*For reference, I used the model [Female Scart Dust Cap for Male Scart Connector](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:6291901)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I figured it out. I thought it was the result of having very small models but it turns out that **simply changing the Filament Color in Cura Filament Profiles** also translates to the Thumbnail color. Using a filament profile with the color black apparently doesn't show depth.

Below is the thumbnail using the original Cura Thumbnail Script and another Filament Color which resulted in the following transparent PNG Thumbnail:

[image: SCART cover 3d model generated by original Cura Thumbnail script]

Instead of the original script I also tried using the Cura script [Cura JPEG Thumbnail creator](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mriscoc/Marlin_Ender3v2/Ender3v2-Released/slicer%20scripts/cura/CreateJPEGThumbnail.py) as described at [How to generate a gcode preview](https://github.com/mriscoc/Ender3V2S1/wiki/How-to-generate-a-gcode-preview) which resulted in the following JPG Thumbnail:

[image: SCART cover 3d model generated by mriscoc Cura Thumbnail script]